# SQL Server Profiler: How to filter on a Session Context key's value?

Tags: sql-server, session, sql-server-profiler, sessioncontext

I am using `SQL Server 2016` in Windows.

There are multiple connections to SQL Server and a database. Each of those connections have a Session Context Key 'CustomerId' and a specific value. So for example there are 3 connections:

- Connection # 1 has Session Context Key 'CustomerId' = 101
- Connection # 2 has Session Context Key 'CustomerId' = 456
- Connection # 3 has Session Context Key 'CustomerId' = 739

Now I have `SQL Server Profiler` open. I want to create a new trace for that SQL Server. But in that trace I only want to see the connection whose Session Context Key 'CustomerId' = 456. How can I do that?

Comment: I arrived here because I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find an answer?